# Save columns from the ps command into arrays

Tags: bash

I'm working on my first bash project and I'm pretty stuck. I want to save several columns from the command `ps -aux` into several arrays, so I can operate on them later. I need each column for all the processes in which I have permission to access the `io` and `status` files.
Do you have any tips? Anything would be helpful!
I don't have any code to show you, because I really don't know how to start this.

Thank you.

Comment: readarray and cut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read array reads lines of input into an array and cut can print specific columns of output.

By combining the two, we can read columns of ps into arrays:

```
readarray ary <<< "$(ps | cut -d " " -f 1)"
```

First run the ps command and pipe it into cut. We want to print the field column so we specify -f1. This output is then redirected into readarray to create an array called ary. The same can be done for other columns by changing the array name and the -f number.

The key here is that the ps | cut command expansion has to be placed in quotes to maintain the new lines.

Comment: You need to get the contents of the array with echo ${ary[@]}

Comment: To get the data in a column, use echo "${ary[@]}"